# mysql calculation with sum from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

if have 2 tables:

```
TABLE "deposit"
card | amount
------------
2 | 123.43
2 | 56.45
3 | 21.19
```

+

```
TABLE "payment"
card | price | status
-----------
2 | 10.59 | finish
2 | 10.59 | pending
10 | 12.40 | finish
2 | 10.59 | finish
```

**What i looking for is the remaining deposit for a card-id.**

Example for card 2: 123.43 + 56.45 - 10.59 - 10.59 (only status = finish)

or: SUM(deposit for card id = 2) - SUM(payment for card id = 2 and status = finish)

I tried the following mysql-select:

```
SELECT(
       IFNULL(SUM(deposit.amount),0) - IFNULL(SUM(payment.price),0)
        ) AS remaing_deposit
        FROM deposit, payment
        WHERE deposit.card = '2'
        OR (
            payment.card = '2' AND payment.status = 'finish'
        )
```

But i get complete wrong Numbers.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You seem to be missing some PRIMARY KEYS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One challenge here is that the two tables have different cards in them.  MySQL doesn't support `full outer join`.  You can get the list of cards doing a `union`.

The rest of the query is solved by aggregating the two tables in the `from` clause an d using `left outer join` on `allcards`:

```
select allcards.card, coalesce(d.deposit, 0) - coalesce(p.price, 0) as RemainingDeposit
from (select card from deposit union
      select card from payment
     ) allcards left outer join
     (select card, sum(amount) as deposit
      from deposit
      group by card
     ) d 
     on d.card = allcards.card left outer join
     (select card, sum(price) as price
      from payment
      where status = 'finish'
      group by card
    ) p
    on p.card = allcards.card;
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick help! It works perfect!!!!

**i add "WHERE card = 2" to get the remainingDeposit for one card.**